# Can SQL Server Data Tools work with SQL Server 2008 SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Can I use the new [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) that come with SQL Server 2012 to create SSIS packages for SQL Server 2008?

I work with both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 and I am wondering if I can use SSDT to create and maintain SSIS on both.

Comment: Not sure, you can give it a try and see but to be safe, use 2008 SSIS editor only to create a SSIS package.

Comment: SSDT is so confusing.  I have already spent a day trying to get it installed.  Was hoping to cut thru some of the BS here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Whilst it may not give you a lot of confidence, the FAQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh322942) states that SSDT will support all versions going back to SQL 2005

Comment: Tough one as there's very little info - as far as I can tell, yes.  But you'll need to use the package deployment model, rather than project deployment, since SSIS 2008 doesn't use the SSIS catalogue DB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. 
See [problem with deploying ssis 2010 package](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlintegrationservices/thread/5edf4335-937f-4b81-aea1-2cd2f10993f4)

It seems that the backward compatibility offered by SSDT does not apply to SSIS.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone wants a smooth integration process that will allow for proficient system performance. In theory, the [SQL Data tools](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) package should work well with server SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) 2008. Get the intended benefits of both systems when each is installed properly.

In theory, SDT should work with SSIS 2008, as the SQL Data tools is compatible with versions of SSIS dating back to 2005. However, more than a few have complained of getting "not supported" error messages. Some have found that answers lie in their installment procedures, while others have used improper versions of SSIS 2008. Overall, however, the underlying issues lie in the unique qualities of the 2008 system.

One important system aspect to keep in mind is the changes that took place when the 2008 version of the integration system was "rolled out." The new features were to better support the day-to-day activities of administrators than the 2005 and other versions. The advancements in individual components of the 2008 version made it more intuitive but, perhaps, inadvertently more complex to integrate with with other systems. For example, its policy-creation configurations are broken into facets, which are meant to be "matched" to the conditions of your policy. While this offers manual control, it's possible that other systems such as SDT will not integrate with 2008 as easily.

In light of the unique qualities of the 2008 version, as opposed to its predecessors, special attention to specific integration maneuvers is necessary. Also keep in mind that the SSIS 2008 R2 version yields more problems than the standard version.

The changes to SQL 2008 also include some discontinuations. In the move to this particular version, there was a large swath of features that were discontinued. As a result, the version lacks much backward compatibility. These conditions may require significant changes in your other systems.