# SQL server 2008 with 2012 Data tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have a SQL server 2008 (10.0.5500) running with VS 2008.
I have recently installed the Data tools for 2012 which are running fine in VS2012.
I have all the new features, the package runs perfect in debug mode, yet i have encoutered a problem by attaching it now to the SQL Agent.
It says "Package migration from version 6 to version 3 failed with error
0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number c
annot be greater than current version number."."

This is because the dtexec.exe is used from 2008 (100 folder). I have only dtexec.exe for 110 folder in x86.

If i specify the specific path to this dtexec, it starts validating but it stops:

```
  Error: 2015-06-09 18:44:48.67
   Code: 0xC000F427
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Merge Join of Integration Services or higher.
End Error
```

The running integration services is version 10, i have gotten no new service for version 11 nor do i see any way to run/install this.

All is done on the same machine, the package should run nightly on the machine it was developed on.

Edit: This is no duplicate, i have all working in VS debug. I'm asking how to schedule my package without dtexec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server Data Tools work with SQL Server 2008 SSIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451053/can-sql-server-data-tools-work-with-sql-server-2008-ssis)

Comment: What do you mean by "schedule my package without dtexec"? Are you not creating a job in the SQL Server Agent on a SQL Server 2008 instance?

Comment: So i designed my whole package, all working fine in debug in VS 2012, and i want it to run nightly. I can't do it with my currently installed Integration Services service that dtexec calls, thus making the sql agent unusable. I've quite given up on getting it to work like that without buying a new SQL 2012 license, which i'd never get our client to do. I'm quite sure they're even fine with something automatically running the package in visual studio debug mode, but i also doubt that's possible..

Answer (score 0):

Integration Services on SQL Server 2008 does not support SSDT/Visual Studio 2010 (or greater) packages.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5edf4335-937f-4b81-aea1-2cd2f10993f4/problem-with-deploying-ssis-2010-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

You must install SQL Server 2012 to get SSDT packages to run.