# Which version of Visual Studio and SSDT-BI need to use for SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssdt-bi

Which version of Visual Studio and SSDT-BI I need to use to create and deploy a SSIS project for SQL server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008` to deploy package for SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server R2 by default. *(newer versions will not work correctly)*

This Link contains very helpful informations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side

There are a lot of links saying that newer versions of visual studio cannot deploy SSIS 2008 packages correctly:

- [Can SQL Server Data Tools work with SQL Server 2008 SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451053/can-sql-server-data-tools-work-with-sql-server-2008-ssis)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bff5e145-1c63-4221-b2ba-009ea96a9e05/can-i-use-vs2012-to-create-and-deploy-ssis-for-sql2008r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1560322-364-1.aspx

But in theory, You can create SSIS 2008 package [using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx). if you decide to try this you can refer to this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/) it may help