# SQL Job sql ssis job ERROR: "the package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 this occurs when CPackage::LoadFROMXML fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2008, sql-job

I created a SSIS Project in **SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013**
now I tried to deploy it as an sql job in sql server 2008. I move the .dstx file and .dtsConfig to another folder.

After selecting the file in the server this error message pops up.

The package failed to load due to:

> error 0xC0010014  "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXM fails.

I tried setting the `Run64BitRuntime` to 'false' but also failed. Because after I close and re-open the project it reverts to true again. I can't find any solution that solves this problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot deploy Sql Server 2008 jobs using Visual Studio 2013 Data Tools, you have to use Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2008**

Visual studio 2013 SSDT work with SQL Server 2014.

```
Target version of SQL Server    |   Development environment for SSIS packages
2016    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015
2014    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013
2012    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
2008    |   Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2008
```

The following link contains very helpful informations:

**For SQL Server 2008 /R2 editions**

- [Integration Services versions Side by side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side)

You have to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008` to deploy package for SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2 by default. *(newer versions will not work correctly)*

There are a lot of links saying that newer versions of visual studio cannot deploy SSIS 2008 packages correctly:

- [Can SQL Server Data Tools work with SQL Server 2008 SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451053/can-sql-server-data-tools-work-with-sql-server-2008-ssis)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bff5e145-1c63-4221-b2ba-009ea96a9e05/can-i-use-vs2012-to-create-and-deploy-ssis-for-sql2008r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1560322-364-1.aspx