# SSIS and SSDT 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, bids

I am developing a SSIS 2008 R2 package in Visual Studio 2015 using SQL Server Data Tools and i am getting the error listed below.  Is these two truly not compatible or is there a setting I can change (or workaround)?

[image]

Comment: You can deploy a ssis 2008 r2 package only using visual studio 2008. The answer provided is 100% correct

Answer (score 2):

You cannot build a ssis package for sql server 2008 r2 with VS 2015.

According to this [Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side) you can build a sql server 2008 r2  ssis package with only visual studio 2008 (business intelligence developpment studio).

There are a lot of links saying that newer versions of visual studio cannot deploy SSIS 2008 packages correctly:

- [Can SQL Server Data Tools work with SQL Server 2008 SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451053/can-sql-server-data-tools-work-with-sql-server-2008-ssis)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bff5e145-1c63-4221-b2ba-009ea96a9e05/can-i-use-vs2012-to-create-and-deploy-ssis-for-sql2008r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1560322-364-1.aspx

Comment: @SteveSalowitz I provided more links in my answer. Take a look